# Phonegap : FileTransfer.upload() fails on Android

Tags: android, upload, cordova, file-transfer

I'm currently trying to upload a picture to a server with the FileTransfer.upload() method of PhoneGap. It works fine on the iPhone Simulator over Wifi, but fails on an Android phone over 3G or Wifi.

alert(error.code) returns '3' but I couldnt find out what this error code is.

Did anybody stumbled upon the same problem and managed to solve it ?
Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783985/phonegaps-filetransfer-upload-throwing-error-code-3-on-android/19268066#19268066

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Today, I tried Simon MacDonald's answer and it worked, so for those who have the same problem. It's certificate related and can be solved simply by adding a 'true' parameter at the end of the upload() function like below :

```
upload(filePath, server, successCallback, errorCallback, options, true);
```

Thank you !

PS: That extra "true" at the end tells upload to accept self signed certs.

Comment: Oh geez, if you would have mentioned it was a https upload I would have told you that from the start ;)

Comment: I was young and not really aware of what I was dealing with back then :)

Comment: O.M.G. that was like a day and a half of development wasted.  thank you so much!!!!

Comment: im using download(encodeURI(URL),target, true)
      .then(...) but always got :
body: null
code: 3
exception: "java.io.EOFException"
http_status: 200
source: "https://ipa....azure.....net......pdf"

Answer (score 17):

Error code 3 is a connection error. Recently we made chunked mode the default for uploading on Android. Try setting your options object to have a chunked mode that is false.

```
var options = FileUploadOptions();
options.chunkedMode = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried it but it still returns '3'. Any other idea ?

Comment: Is there anyway to display more information about this error. Something better than error.code.

Comment: By chance are you trying to upload to a https site using a self signed cert? For logging what do you see in "adb logcat" or on the server logs?

Comment: Yes, I am actually uploading to an https site. I can't tell you right now what are the logs but I will as soon as I can get my hands on a Android Simulator. Thank you

Comment: If you are uploading to a https site with a self signed certificate you need to add an extra parameter on upload. Try 

    upload(filePath, server, successCallback, errorCallback, options, true);

that extra "true" at the end tells upload to accept self signed certs.

Comment: Being on holidays for the next two weeks, I can't test your solutions for the moment. Anyway, thank you very much. I'll get back to you asap. Thanks again

Comment: Hi Simon, First - thank you for that answer. 
1. I have spent the entire day until I got to your answer. Can you guys add that to cordova file Android (4.*) Quirk (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) to save users time in the future?


2. What are the benefits from running `chunkedMode=true`? Should I run my ios version of the app with that settings?

Comment: If anyone had problems with $_POST and $_FILES being empty on server side, setting chunkedMode to false helped me