# Phonegap's FileTransfer.upload() throwing error code 3 on Android

Tags: android, cordova, upload

I am working on uploading a picture to a server. I am able to successfully upload an image using iOS but when i try on android I get the error code 3. Currently using phonegap cordova 1.8.1.

I already tried adding true to the parameters

```
upload(filePath, server, successCallback, errorCallback, options, **true**);
```

and adding this

```
options.chunkedMode = false;
```

My AndroidManifest file contains:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My cordova.xml file contains:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I have same error code on iOS, how how you solved your problem?

Comment: Error code meanings: 1 = FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR
         2 = FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR
         3 = FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR
         4 = FileTransferError.ABORT_ERR
         5 = FileTransferError.NOT_MODIFIED_ERR

Answer (score 7):

The issue probably is not in Phonegap. if the server is a Windows based server, try using another server. Also, don´t forget to add these lines:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.headers = {
      Connection: "close"
   };
```

Comment: This worked for me with a PHP webservice on a window server machine. Thanks a lot

Comment: After trying many things, over several hours, this worked for me for Ruby webserver (Roda) on a windows machine. Thanks!

Comment: I needed `chunkedMode`, but `Connection: "close"` header worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

add code:

```
var op;
op = new FileUploadOptions();

op.headers = {
    Connection: "close"
};
```

After adding this - code started to work well with no errors.
A bit more detailed description: http://grandiz.com/phonegap-development/phonegap-file-transfer-error-code-3-solved
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too. You should specify  `chunkedMode=false` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522729/phonegap-filetransfer-upload-fails-on-android)

```
var options = FileUploadOptions();
options.chunkedMode = false;
```

Comment: Sorry, disabling chunked mode did not help.

Answer (score 2):

These are steps I used to overcome this problem:

Added the following options:

```
options.chunkedMode = false;
options.headers = {
      Connection: "close"
   };
```

But more important was the fact that I was using Genymotion as the emulator for testing. Uploading the image to localhost was not working because the emulator was running in a VM and localhost meant the VM's localhost and not the localhost of your web server.

So instead of uploading to 'localhost', you should upload to:

```
http://10.0.2.2
```

and add the following line to your config.xml:

```
<access origin="10.0.2.2" subdomains="true"/>
```

I tested it and its working like a charm. Took me 3 days to get this working though.

Comment: `Connection: "close"` header worked for me. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfixed bug in the phonegap library, since there were no bug fixes, i had to get it work by my work around (Basically reupload on every alternate failure):

```
ft.upload(path,
          encodeURI("http://yourdomain.com/upload.php"),
            function(result) {
                alert("Uploaded");
            },
            function(error) {
                ft.upload(path,
                encodeURI("http://yourdomain.com/upload.php"),
                function(result) {
                    alert("Uploaded");                  
                },
                function(error) {
                    alert("Error uploading image");
                },
                { fileName: name, fileKey: "file", mimeType: "image/jpeg", chunkedMode: false }, true);     
            },
            { fileName: name, fileKey: "file", mimeType: "image/jpeg", chunkedMode: false }, true);
```

Comment: Didn't solve my issue, straggling with this for a week now. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've asked Telerik about this issue that I experience with AppBuilder. According to their response [it might be a bug in Cordova](http://www.telerik.com/forums/code-3-upload-error-on-android-4-3-when-uploading-to-s3) (I'm using 3.2).

They recommend updating to the l[atest FileTransfer library](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer) (also update all the dependencies) and see if that solves your issue. I actually ran into another problem compiling the new libraries.

I recommend trying that and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a reason, and solved it for me:

iOS 9 and OSX 10.11 require TLSv1.2 SSL for all hosts you plan to request data from unless you specify exception domains in your app's Info.plist file.

([CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9))

Answer (score -1):

You can try either of these:

Set `android:debuggable="true"` in the `<application>` tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Set `<access origin=".*"/>` instead of just the `*` as it's recommended in the comments section as follows:

```
<!-- <access origin="https://example.com" /> allow any secure requests to example.com -->
<!-- <access origin="https://example.com" subdomains="true" /> such as above, but including subdomains, such as www -->
<!-- <access origin=".*"/> Allow all domains, suggested development use only -->
```