# Code 3 when uploading file to S3 using FileTransfer in Phonegap on Android 4.3

Tags: javascript, android, file-upload, cordova, amazon-s3

I am getting "**Code 3**" (connection error) error when trying to upload an image file from my Cordova / Phonegap 3.2 app **to Amazon S3** using FileTransfer and in **Android 4.3** version platform.

```
 options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = filename_for_s3;
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.headers = {
        Connection: "close"
    }

ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("https://" + data.Bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com/"), success, fail, options);
```

The code works on iOS7 and older Android versions (tested on Android 3.2 and 2.3), but my problem is with version 4.3.  I assume that the problem is not with the code itself, as it works with other version, but might be the Phonegap library itself.

There might be a workaround but I am not familiar with it. I tried many options posted on what it seems like a similar problem, like changing the chunkedMode to false, without encoding the URI, adding "Connection: 'close'" header but it still doesn't work. Others suggested that this might be an issue with the google analytics plugin that causes it, so I removed it and I still get the same error. I also tried the answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629135/phonegap-android-filetransfer-error-code-3) without success.

I also want to add that I am generating a signature and policy on the server.

```
  options.params = {

     "key": "uploads/" + filename_for_s3,
     "AWSAccessKeyId": data.AWSAccessKey,
     'success_action_status': '201',
     "acl": "private",
     "policy": data.Policy,
     "signature": data.Signature

                };
```

Cors permissions are also set as needed:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>ETag</ExposeHeader>
    <ExposeHeader>x-amz-meta-custom-header</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Update: I also checked the Amazon S3 logs, but there isn't any line related to an upload.

I've spent a few days trying to figure it out without any success. I hope that you can help me solve this issue. Thanks.

It seems like this is a **bug** in Cordova 3.2 ([see my post here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/code-3-upload-error-on-android-4-3-when-uploading-to-s3)). I was suggested to use the latest FileTransfer library, and also updated the File library, however [I get an error when compiling](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-use-cordova-3-4).

I need help to solve this issue.

**Update:** updating the FileTransfer, File and Capture plugins to the newest version didn't solve the problem, in fact, now it throws Code 3 on iOS7 too - didn't happen before.

Comment: For your `filekey`, have you tried putting `document`? Also, make sure that you can upload publicly to S3 that way. I've used S3 a little, but from what I remember you usually have to pass some sort of access key and secret in the URL.

Comment: I will try the document. I also use signature and policy that works on other platforms (updated the question with the params I am passing). Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewLively changing to document type didn't help.

Comment: i'm not familiar with Phonegap, but are you sure that you are calling (the upload function) inside an Asynctask, or using another thread to call upload function inside phonegap.

Comment: i found this if this could help you:
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/04/sorry-for-being-gone-so-long-vacation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `ft.upload(imageURI,"https://" + data.Bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com/", success, fail, options);` ? Looks like you are URL encoding the :// parts of the url.

Comment: Yep, I tried without encoding the URL. As I mentioned, it works on android 2,3 iOS7 without an issue even with encoded URL, the only issue is in 4.3 that I tried, probably in other 4.xx versions.

Comment: You probably seen this already, but just in case: http://grandiz.com/phonegap-development/phonegap-file-transfer-error-code-3-solved/

Comment: I know everything points to a Cordova bug, but have you tried a smaller/different image, different bucket or even a different upload location (like a test php file on your server)?

Answer (score 1):

kindly try this

```
ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("https://" + data.Bucket + ".s3.amazonaws.com/"), success, fail, options, true);
```

I have added true at the last. Because its a accepts all certificates. By defaults it will reject self signed certificates. Now you are using https. I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

I also got the error code 3 when I tried to download a pdf-file.
I also tried to pass `Connection: 'close'`, update plugins etc. - nothing worked. Eventually I just started to use a `XMLHttpRequest` in combination with `cordova-plugin-file`:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory, function(entry) {
    entry.getFile('myfile.pdf', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function(fileEntry) {
        downloadFile(fileEntry, url);
    }, onCreateFileError);
}, onResolveError);

function downloadFile(fileEntry, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
            fileWriter.write(new Blob([xhr.response]));
        });
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

This code is for downloading, but I think the same approach can be applied for uploading.