# cordova FileTransfert work one time on two error 3

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I've got a strange issue with fileTransfert plugin of cordova (Target device is Android 4.3 and it works on Android 6.0). 
I just arrive to upload one file on two.
The first and third sending work well, but the second returns an error code 3 with this error message in logs:

```
E/FileTransfer(15179): {"target":"https:\/\/XXXX\/uploadTeamPicture","http_status":0,"code":3,"source":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/Pictures\/2017_4_14\/XXXXX_14-15-00.jpeg","exception":"Write error: ssl=0x6e653128: I\/O error during system call, Broken pipe"}
```

This is the function

```
// Manage File sending
function uploadFile(webAddr,fileURL,params)
{
    // when it's finished
    var win = function (r) {

       alert("Picture has been sent correctly !","Information"); 
       $("#takePicture").hide();
       resetAppli();
       fileTrans.abord();
    };
    // if upload failed
    var fail = function (error) {
        var msg="Please take another picture \n"; 
        msg+="An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code;
        msg+="\n src:"+error.source;
        msg+="\n trgt:"+error.target;
        alert(msg);
        $("#takePicture").hide();
        resetAppli();
    };


    var uri = encodeURI(webAddr);

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="fileToUpload";
    options.fileName=fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="text/plain";

    var headers={'headerParam':'headerValue'};

    options.headers = headers;
    options.params = params;

    //var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var ft=fileTrans;
    ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
            //loadingStatus.setPercentage(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
            uploadProgress(progressEvent);
            var infoProg=(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
            console.log("Progress :" + infoProg);
        } else {
            //loadingStatus.increment();
        }
    };
    // init progress bar before sending
    initProgressBar();
    // send file
    ft.upload(fileURL, uri, win, fail, options);

}
```

If somebody has an idea ... 
Many Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution here :
[Code 3 when uploading file to S3 using FileTransfer in Phonegap on Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452840/code-3-when-uploading-file-to-s3-using-filetransfer-in-phonegap-on-android-4-3)

Just add true option at the end of parameters table.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line of the function

```
ft.upload(fileURL, uri, win, fail, options);
```

To this:

```
ft.upload(fileURL, uri, win, fail, options, true);
```

And this line:

```
var headers={'headerParam':'headerValue'};
```

To this:

```
var headers={Connection:'close'};
```