# Xcode 7.0 Swift Update Problems

Tags: xcode, swift2

I'm trying to update my project to work with Xcode 7.0 and after updating my Swift projects I'm getting an error that I don't understand on this line.

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
```

The error is

*"Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled"*

I'm also getting these two errors in my project files...

*"linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"*

and

*"error: cannot parse the debug map for "/Users/MattFiler/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ePlanner-cqwzlxqgpwaloubjgnzdlomjkfea/Build/Intermediates/SwiftMigration/ePlanner/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ePlannerTests.xctest/ePlannerTests": No such file or directory"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
    // Use jsonData here
} catch {
    print("Well something happened: \(error)")
}
```

You'll need the `try` keyword as `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` now throws an error if something failed since Swift 2. Throwing functions need to be marked with `try` or `try!`.

Also you'll need the `do { ... } catch` to catch any errors that may occur. This will catch the error and handle it.

You might want to read up on the [changes in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/RevisionHistory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH40-ID459) to understand why this happened. Also the WWDC videos will be very helpful.

Comment: Helpful, thanks. I don't know why they have to update the language, it's annoying for learners like me.

Comment: @MattFiler Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem and upvote if it exceeded your expectations

Comment: Have done, thank you! I'm also using a UIWebView in my project and I'm now getting the error of "NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)" after the Xcode update. Do you know what could be causing this? It worked absolutely fine before but now it won't load my webpages.

Comment: @MattFiler nope, don't know. Seems to be something SSL-related. Search the error domain (`kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL`) and error code (`9802`). Make a new question if you can't find it.

Comment: Thanks. After searching it seems a few people are having the same problem, this one fixed it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9-beta-1

Answer (score 1):

You need to try and catch if it throws an error.

```
do {
    let jsonData:NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSDictionary
    //...
}
catch {
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, but then later in the code I get errors saying that the variable is an "unresolved identifier" when I try and call 'jsonData'.

Comment: Did you use `jsonData` inside the `do` block?