# Swift 2.0 : Cannot invoke with an argument list of type... (HTTP Request)

Tags: swift, swift2

Since I upgraded to Xcode 7 beta I have an error that I can't fix.
Here's the full code from my DataManager.swift

```
import Foundation
var TopAppURL:String = String()
var numberAsked:String = String()

class DataManager {


class func getInfo(ID : String){
    TopAppURL = "http://sweetapi.com/?=\(ID)"
    numberAsked = ID
    }


class func loadDataFromURL(url: NSURL, completion:(data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        // Use NSURLSession to get data from an NSURL
    let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if let responseError = error {
            completion(data: nil, error: responseError)
        } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                var statusError = NSError(domain:"com.raywenderlich", code:httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP status code has unexpected value."])
                completion(data: nil, error: statusError)
            } else {
                completion(data: data, error: nil)
            }
        }
    })

    loadDataTask.resume()
}

class func getDataFromSweetApiOk(success: ((IDdata: NSData!) -> Void)) {
    //1
    print("DataManager loads \(TopAppURL)")
    loadDataFromURL(NSURL(string: TopAppURL)!, completion:{(data, error) -> Void in
        //2
        if let urlData = data {
            //3
            success(IDdata: urlData)
        }
    })
}
}
```

So I got this error : "Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithURL' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, completionHandler: (NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> Void)'"
I searched everywhere how to fix this but like Swift 2.0 is very new, I didn't found any solution.

Comment: Did you check the signature of `dataTaskWithURL`?

Comment: No, and the problem was here ! Thanks a lot !  `let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in`
         is now `let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in` and it just works !

Comment: Uuuh I spoke too fast, it now compiles but I got `2015-06-09 23:07:08.378 App[2930:77022] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2015-06-09 23:07:08.379 App[2930:77022] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)` and the app didn't load anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
func dataTaskWithURL(_ url: NSURL,
   completionHandler completionHandler: ((NSData!,
                              NSURLResponse!,
                              NSError!) -> Void)?) -> NSURLSessionDataTask
```

has changed to

```
func dataTaskWithURL(_ url: NSURL,
   completionHandler completionHandler: (NSData?,
                              NSURLResponse?,
                              NSError?) -> Void) -> NSURLSessionDataTask?
```

in iOS9. The completionHandler no longer is optional, and all parameters in the completionHandler are now optionals instead of implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Now, to help with this in future changes to the optional system, try to avoid `(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in`, you can simply use `data, response, error in` and then option-click for more details.

This will remove bloat from your code, and thus improve readability.

To solve your problem in the comments, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9-beta-1).