# NSURLSession "HTTP load failed kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813 ; Self signing certificate

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https

I'm trying to connect my iOS app to an HTTPS Rails app which is currently run on a local host in my network. I can access the site from my browser with `https://myIP:3000/display` as well as in the command line with a curl request. I'm trying to access it from my app using:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //let url = NSURL(string: "https://another/Sinatra/website/feed")
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://myIP:3000/display")

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!)
        task!.resume()
    }
```

When I try to access the sinatra website I have no trouble and can even print out the JSON to the console with the correct commands. However, when I set url to my Rails website I get the following error.

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

In addition, I can tell that my localhost Rails app (on the other machine) is not pinged from the iOS app, but is pinged from the browser and curl command.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Put your code in `viewWillDisplay` or `viewDidDisplay`. `viewDidLoad` is to early for most things.

Comment: Which iOS and Swift version? Add that information to the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed iOS 9 Beta 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9-beta-1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed)

Comment: Also happens in Objective C   (not only on swift)

Answer (score 43):

If I understood well, Apple now wants the developers to use HTTPS and TLS 1.2 for network calls.

**Temporary**, you can add this in your "Info.plist" file :

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Just have a look to this link, it may also help you : [http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/5857#5857)

--

**Update** : Following some comments the above solution is not anymore working. Here is an updated solution.

1. Go to your `Info.plist` file.
2. Add a row of *Type* `Dictionary` and of *Key* `App Transport Security Settings`.
3. In this Dictionary, add a row of *Type* `Boolean`, of *Key* `Allow Arbitrary Loads` and of *Value* `YES`

[image]

**-**

Otherwise you can set `Domain Exceptions`. This is how to do :

1. Go to your `Info.plist` file.
2. Add a row of *Type* `Dictionary` and of *Key* `App Transport Security Settings`.
3. Add a row of *Type* `Dictionary` and of *Key* `Exception Domains`.
4. Add a row of *Type* `Dictionary` and of *Key* `The domain`.
5. Add two rows of *Type* `Boolean` and of *Key* `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` & `NSIncludesSubdomains` with *Value* to `YES`.

### [image]

**Links**

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/5857#5857

[2015 WWDC Session 711](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=711)

[iOS 9 HTTP Connection Error - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127376/ios9-http-connection-error)

Comment: Not just https, but it has to be TLS 1.2.

Comment: This does not seem to work in the iOS simulator. Have you got it working in the simulator?

Comment: No longer working with iOS 10.  What's the fix? (Thanks to Apple for letting us know they would break our apps - NOT :-)

Comment: Funny, I'm getting a similar error with a TLS 1.2 connection. This is talking to a production server with a real SSL certificate. The Allow Arbitrary Loads makes this work.

Answer (score 20):

This is a trust issue.  With a self-signed certificate, the identity verification component of SSL does not work.  It's still possible to establish a secure connection so that nobody is eavesdropping, but the app cannot be sure of who is on the other end of the line.

I have a similar setup, and solved this issue by adding my self-signed root CA to the iPad trusted certificates. This root CA is used to sign all of my other development certificates.  Then I just have to add this single root certificate anywhere that SSL will be used.  If you just have a self-signed certificate that you are using directly, you can probably just add that.

To get the certificate onto the device (or simulator), I put the file on my web server.  Then just open it in Safari over plain HTTP.  The Settings app should open and ask if you want to trust the certificate.

Of course this is assuming that this is for development only, and that your production system has a certificate signed by a well-known authority (i.e. one included in the OS' database of root certificate authorities).  Because asking end users to install your self-signed certificate won't fly.

Comment: Yeah but which file did you put on your server? I put my .cert and Safari just opens it as a text file.

Comment: I put my self-signed root CA on the server and opened it in Safari.  I used the extension `.crt`

Comment: My server is using a _real_ certificate (not self-signed) and I'm still getting this issue...

Answer (score 6):

This is the only solution worked for me... At the end of your AppDelegate.m file, insert the code:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)

    + (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
    {
        return YES;
    }

@end
```

Thanks for jc ivancevich article http://ivancevich.me/articles/ignoring-invalid-ssl-certificates-on-cordova-android-ios/

Answer (score 1):

*(Edit - I misread this as 9814, expired cert.  I'm not sure how to solve this one, but hopefully my response helps point in the right direction.)*

Looks like a cert issue different from the usual "Allow Arbitrary Loads" question.

Brief excerpt from: [Apple Documentation - Appendix A: Common Server Trust Evaluation Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html//apple_ref/doc/navigation/)

NSOSStatusErrorDomain errSSLNoRootCert -9813

Answer (score 1):

try change the session variable, this change help me

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the info.plist worked for me as well.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score -4):

NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Add a new row in your plist file.[image]

Comment: This is just a repeat of the existing answers.