# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) in iOS 9 with Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, http, nsurlsession, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am using iOS 9 as target & using Xcode 7.1, tried everything as my level best for all the solutions of ATS but didn't work. Below is the following error description coming at console. If any suggestion comes I will be obliged.

Some of the key things here are -

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Error excluding Main.db from backup Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “Main.db” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///Users/Raj/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BC3A0589-3B9A-4AFD-8F2A-B1C92FA341DD/data/Containers/Data/Application/70B3043A-8553-41E5-A147-8508D08BF3E6/Documents/Main.db, NSFilePath=/Users/Raj/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BC3A0589-3B9A-4AFD-8F2A-B1C92FA341DD/data/Containers/Data/Application/70B3043A-8553-41E5-A147-8508D08BF3E6/Documents/Main.db, NSUnderlyingError=0x798465c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
2016-08-30 21:09:10.867 GFIM[80653:484899] SFOAuthCredentials:revokeRefreshToken: refresh token revoked. Cleared identityUrl, instanceUrl, issuedAt fields
2016-08-30 21:09:10.871 GFIM[80653:484899] INFO|0|SFPasscodeManager|Resetting passcode upon logout.

SFOAuthCredentials:revokeRefreshToken: refresh token revoked. Cleared identityUrl, instanceUrl, issuedAt fields
```

These are the things might be the cause of issue.

```
2016-08-30 21:09:19.095 GFIM[80653:484899] SFOAuthCoordinator:webViewDidStartLoad: host=test.salesforce.com : path=/
2016-08-30 21:09:19.863 GFIM[80653:484962] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2016-08-30 21:09:19.983 GFIM[80653:484962] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2016-08-30 21:09:20.016 GFIM[80653:484962] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2016-08-30 21:09:20.054 GFIM[80653:484962] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2016-08-30 21:09:20.194 GFIM[80653:484962] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2016-08-30 21:09:20.956 GFIM[80653:484962] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
2016-08-30 21:09:38.285 GFIM[80653:484899] SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=1): host=test.salesforce.com : path=/
2016-08-30 21:09:38.311 GFIM[80653:484899] SFOAuthCoordinator:webViewDidStartLoad: host=test.salesforce.com : path=/
2016-08-30 21:09:38.834 GFIM[80653:484899] SFOAuthCoordinator:webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (navType=1): host=5-prod--stg.cs30.my.salesforce.com : path=/secur/frontdoor.jsp
```

Answer (score 11):

If you try to make HTTP requests with ATS enabled (using NSURLSession or libraries like AFNetworking), you’ll see errors like this.

Here’s how to disable ATS entirely. Open Info.plist, and add the following lines:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
```

Your info.plist file should look like this

[image]

See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31077483/6763322

Comment: I did it but not working... Should I use http instead of https.

Comment: If i use http then its showing "Remote Access Application Authorization".

Comment: This is missing a 5th line: `</dict>`

Answer (score 11):

From iOS 9 Onwards Apple Enforce To make HTTP Request with Specific Host for Security Purpose.
//Also works on iOS 10 with Swift 3

For that, you need to Add `NSAppTransportSecurity` Dictionary into your `.plist` the file of Project. Then your `plist` will look something like this as follows.

[Tap to see .Plist File Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSlUr.png)

Here `NSAllowArbitraryLoads` basically means  Connect to anything (this is probably BAD). Instead of this you can add a particular Host to be Connect.

[image]

Comment: I changed in my case its showing "App Transport Security Setting" inside that i have changed "Allow Arbitary load" Yes still it's not working.Any idea why?

Comment: This will flag your app during review and you will have to justify your reasoning. Use AllowsArbitraryLoads for testing only. You need to explicitly list domains in production apps.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran it in the device instead of simulator.It started working

Answer (score 0):

For those who are working in xcode 8...this will help you...
[image]