# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) in youtube player

Tags: ios, youtube-iframe-api

I'm using YouTube helper library to embed video in iOS app(https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper).

I'm getting following message in console while running app and showing black color in youtube player view. Message is

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

I have also `enabled arbitary loads of transport security` in info.plist file,but still it's not working.

Comment: look at; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232510/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9813-i