# FileProvider WebDav HTTP load failed

Tags: ios, swift, http, webdav, fileprovider

I am using https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider to access my WebDav server, do load some logs onto it.

It was working great for some time, but now every time I use copyItem I get a HTTP load failed.

This is the relevant code:

```
let server: URL = URL(string: "https://my.powerfolder.com/webdav")!
var webdav: WebDAVFileProvider?
webdav = WebDAVFileProvider(baseURL: server, credential: credential)!
webdav?.copyItem(localFile: url, to: remotePath, completionHandler: nil)
```

And this is the error which is thrown in runtime:

```
2019-05-04 11:45:31.398089+0200 TestApp[319:45293] Task <93EC5684-2840-4A9D-B6E0-5FB46E1D7D09>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
```

Any ideas, what the problem could be? As the App suddenly stopps working, I think it must be something with an iOS update on my iPad.

I already updated my XCode and the FileProvider via git pull, but nothing changes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you set true for `NSAllowArbitraryLoads`? see the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235512/603127

Comment: I added this to my info.plist, but sadly it didn't change anything.