# HTTPS connection error on MAMP server

Tags: https, swift2, ios9, xcode7-beta6

I have setup a MAMP server and configured an SSL site. I have verified it works with a call (https://app.dev:8890/login/hello.html) to a simple html file.

i found a test app that woks and connects to a remote server with no issues.

I modified the app to connect using my local MAMP server....

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://app.dev:8890/login/jsonsignup.php")!
```

when I run it and try getting to that page I receive this error....

> 2015-09-04 13:04:19.679 SwiftLoginScreen[14905:437125] PostData: username=uname&password=pword&c_password=pword
>   2015-09-04 13:04:19.693 SwiftLoginScreen[14905:441196] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
>   2015-09-04 13:04:19.695 SwiftLoginScreen[14905:441196] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
>   2015-09-04 13:04:19.697 SwiftLoginScreen[14905:441196] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
>   2015-09-04 13:04:19.697 SwiftLoginScreen[14905:441196] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)

I do not want to disable ATS I just need to see where my issue is with this connection.

Comment: Correction here. I meant the App Transfer Security (ATS) protocol

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting on it. While you are at it, you might want to use some markup for the log output...

Comment: I went back and edited it shortly after i realized I could. thank you

Comment: I cannot help you concretely, but it seems like the word to google for is ``kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL``.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9

Comment: How did you solve that? I'm having your same issue now...

Comment: I have not. I moved on to another project and am just now getting back to it.