# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed , -9802

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After Successfully running the program the error will be shows on debug area

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

protocol ItemDetailViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func itemDetailViewControllerDidCancel(controller: ItemDetailViewController)
    func itemDetailViewController(controller: ItemDetailViewController, didFinishAddingItem item: NoToDoItem)
    func itemDetailViewController(controller: ItemDetailViewController, didFinishEditingItem item: NoToDoItem)

}

class ItemDetailViewController: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBAction func myLocation(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.LocationManager.delegate = self
        self.LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    let LocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var doneBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var dueDateLabel: UILabel!

    weak var delegate: ItemDetailViewControllerDelegate?

    var itemToEdit: NoToDoItem?
    var dueDate = NSDate()
    var datePickerVisible = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if let item = itemToEdit {
            title = "Edit Item"
            textField.text = item.text
            descriptionTextView.text = item.text
            dueDate = item.dueDate
            doneBarButton.enabled = true
        }

        updateDueDateLabel()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                print("Error")
                return
            }

            if let pm = placemarks?.first
            {
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }
            else {
                print("errorData")
            }

        })

    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark){
        self.LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print(placemark.locality)
        print(placemark.postalCode)
        print(placemark.administrativeArea)
        print(placemark.country)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error:" + error.localizedDescription)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        let oldText: NSString = textField.text!
        let newText: NSString = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        doneBarButton.enabled = (newText.length > 0)
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let item = itemToEdit {
            item.text = textField.text!

            textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            item.text = descriptionTextView.text!
            descriptionTextView.becomeFirstResponder()

            item.dueDate = dueDate

            delegate?.itemDetailViewController(self, didFinishEditingItem: item)
        } else {
            let item = NoToDoItem()
            item.text = textField.text!
            item.dueDate = dueDate

            delegate?.itemDetailViewController(self, didFinishAddingItem: item)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.itemDetailViewControllerDidCancel(self)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 1
        {
            return indexPath
        } else {
            return nil
        } 
    }

    func updateDueDateLabel() {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
        dueDateLabel.text = formatter.stringFromDate(dueDate)
    }

    func showDatePicker() {

        datePickerVisible = true

        let indexPathDateRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 2)
        let indexPathDatePicker = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 2)

        if let dateCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathDateRow)
        {
            dateCell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = dateCell.detailTextLabel!.tintColor
        }
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathDatePicker],withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathDateRow], withRowAnimation: .None)

        tableView.endUpdates()

        if let pickerCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath( indexPathDatePicker) {
            let datePicker = pickerCell.viewWithTag(100) as! UIDatePicker
            datePicker.setDate(dueDate, animated: false)}
    }

    func hideDatePicker()
    {
        if datePickerVisible {
            datePickerVisible = false
            let indexPathDateRow = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 2)
            let indexPathDatePicker = NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 2)
            if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathDateRow) {
                cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
            }
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathDateRow], withRowAnimation: .None)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathDatePicker], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 2 && datePickerVisible { return 3
        } else {
            return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
        } 
     }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2 {
            return 217
        } else {
            return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        } 
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // 1
        if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2 { // 2
            var cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DatePickerCell")

            if cell == nil {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default,
                    reuseIdentifier: "DatePickerCell")
                cell.selectionStyle = .None
                // 3
                let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                    width: 320, height: 216))
                datePicker.tag = 100
                cell.contentView.addSubview(datePicker)
                // 4
                datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dateChanged:"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
            }
            return cell
            // 5
        } else {
            return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool{

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        hideDatePicker()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()


        if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 1 { if !datePickerVisible {
            showDatePicker()
        }
        else
        {
            hideDatePicker()
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, var indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
        if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2 {
            indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: indexPath.section)
        }
        return super.tableView(tableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool{

        if text == "\n"
        {
            descriptionTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func dateChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        dueDate = datePicker.date
        updateDueDateLabel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What did you do to debug? Where is it failing? What's your specific question? Also, would you mind editing your question to correct the code formatting please?

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9?

Comment: After running the program it will shows the error in debug pane .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add just the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES in NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your info.plist file.

For example,

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

[image]