# Can't download image artwork from iTunes

Tags: ios

I'm trying to download an image from iTunes with a valid URL - but the image is NOT being downloaded. Here is the link:

http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music7/v4/53/fc/a2/53fca253-84b1-f2cd-4e17-98be502ec53c/UMG_cvrart_00602547534873_01_RGB72_1500x1500_15UMGIM41882.jpg/60x60bb-85.jpg

Now when I try to download the image, it returns NULL for some strange reason:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://is5.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music7/v4/53/fc/a2/53fca253-84b1-f2cd-4e17-98be502ec53c/UMG_cvrart_00602547534873_01_RGB72_1500x1500_15UMGIM41882.jpg/60x60bb-85.jpg"]];
```

This is only happening for artwork for iTunes links.

> (lldb) po imageData
>   nil

Comment: The problem was with iOS 9:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a while, but in case others are looking for a solution to this ...

In iOS 9 Apple started requiring App Transport Security on URLs.  This means that "http:" needs to be replaced by "https:".

When you get an image URL like artworkUrl60 it still comes as "http:" because Apple doesn't want to break existing applications.

The logical thing to do is to replace the "http:" with "https:".

But that doesn't work!  It doesn't even work if you paste it into a browser because the mzstatic.com website doesn't appear to have a valid certificate.

The solution is to either completely turn off ATS (not recommended) or to white-list mzstatic.com.

Open Info.plist and insert the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mzstatic.com</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

That appears to fix the problem.

David

Comment: I just filed radar 27625853 on this.

Comment: Question is, will Apple accept that when submitting to the app store?  That is my biggest concern.

Comment: I got several apps into the App Store that way.  It's the standard solution to this and similar problems.  That was about 12 months ago.  Don't know about today.

Comment: Hi David, looks like they still haven't added an ssl certificate to itunes :(

Comment: Is the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` false necessary? Isn't that the default?

Comment: Experiment ... and post the results.