# Trouble installing certain Paw extensions

Tags: paw-app

I'm unable to install almost any of the Paw extensions. Unfortunately several of the ones that won't install are the ones I really want! :)

I've tried almost all the code generators, and only found one that would install. e.g.

- Swift + NSURLSession Code Generator — does not install
- JavaScript + jQuery Code Generator — does not install
- Objective-C + NSURLConnection Code Generator — does not install
- WordPress Code Generator — does not install

The one that works:

- Betamax.py Generator — does install

For those that don't work, the following appears in the console:

`30/09/15 7:21:11.328 PM Paw[9673]: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I am running El Capitan. Which OS version are you using?

Comment: Same, El Capitan, although in my case it's the beta, i.e. 10.11.1 beta (15B22c)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, it now has been fixed. https://luckymarmot.com/paw/updates/2.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now fixed in [Paw 2.2.5](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/updates/2.2.5), which is ready now on the website, or in a couple of days on the Mac App Store.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for getting this sorted so quickly.

Comment: Sure thing. It was exactly the problem @dclobato described!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a "problem" with El Capitan. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9) question, iOS 9 and **OSX 10.11** require TLSv1.2 SSL for all hosts you plan to request data from unless you specify exception domains in your app's Info.plist file.

I tried to manually edit Info.plist and add

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Connect to anything (this is probably BAD)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

But, after that, I just could not start Paw anymore and got the following line on console

```
07/10/15 00:39:15,398 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.luckymarmot.Paw.103392[905]) Service exited due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4
```

Comment: Good call. That was exactly the problem + some error/alert bug introduced by El Capitan too. Thanks a lot, and sorry for the issue.