# Code Generator extension doesn't install

Tags: paw-app

Trying to install "Objective-C + NSURLSession Code Generator" in a trial version of Paw fails with a bonk sound - no message. Is installation of extensions disabled for the trial version?

Comment: Definitely not, it should be working. I'll check this right now and keep you updated. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I was too impatient to wait. I purchased/installed from Mac AppStore. After installation, extensions loaded without problem. May help others (and potentially your sales) to post an answer to how to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This version fixes the problem: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/updates/2.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Are you on OS X 10.11?  It seems to be a "problem" with El Capitan. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9) question, iOS 9 and **OSX 10.11 require TLSv1.2 SSL** for all hosts you plan to request data from unless you specify exception domains in your app's Info.plist file.

BTW, another user posted a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859273/trouble-installing-certain-paw-extensions).

Comment: Thanks for the input. If this is the issue, maybe it is not so much a "problem" with El Capitan as it is with the luckymarmot.com extension server not conforming to Apple's newly enforced security practices: TLS version 1.2 with cryptographic algorithms that provide forward secrecy with a certificate with a SHA256 hash algorithm and 2048-bit RSA or 256-bit ECC or better.