# xcode 7 swift webview https output statment

Tags: swift, webview, xcode7

xcode 7 swift, I am using https for my webview, the app load the page sucessfully, but it said `"2015-10-05 18:03:51.204 HKCateringApp[1326:45336] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)"`
Please help to solve it. Here with my code:

```
    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://www.ssls.com")

    WebView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: URL!))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed iOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9)

Comment: Did you check AppTransport Security in info.plist ???

Answer (score 1):

You have to add just the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES in NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your info.plist file. Something new in iOS 9.0, So you have to do this.

For example,

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

Comment: Could you please guide me how to do it? I am new to use xcode and couldn't find NSAppTransportSecurity

Comment: See, This Tutorial -> http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/    || http://i.stack.imgur.com/CnBlN.png

Comment: You will not find the key  NSAppTransportSecurity. You have to manually paste it there and enter, And save its value to YES. And thats it.

Comment: open Info.plist as source and paste inside main <dict>...</dict>