# MobileFirst 6.3 iOS CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824) while server supports TLS1.2

Tags: ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, tls1.2

I am getting a "CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)" message on my iOS app using MobileFirst 6.3.

Using the following suggestion I can solve the issue, but I don't like it because of vulnerability.
[CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9)

In my Build and Deploy target I have configured my server URL as https and my server supports TLS1.2. Why does it still give this error? The app connects over port 443.

Is it possible to configure MF6.3 to connect in a secure way to my MobileFirst server?

Comment: Have you read the blog posts for server compatibility with iOS9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make to sure the follow the instructions provided in this blog post: [How to enable App Transport Security for iOS 9 in IBM MobileFirst Platform Server](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/).

The blog post is exhaustive, so I will not summarize it here...

Comment: Thanks, it was an issue in the cipher configuration of our http server