# How to fix an Adobe Air SSL error that prevents images from loading

Tags: ssl, air, adobe

I'm new to Adobe Air.  I'm building my first app in it.  It is not a Flash app.  Here is my application.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.7">
    <id>iViewDesktop</id>
    <name>Patient Education</name>
    <filename>Patient Education</filename>
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
    <installFolder>patient-education</installFolder>
    <initialWindow>
        <title>Patient Education</title>
        <content>redirect.html</content>
        <description>This is an Adobe Air version of Patient Education</description>
        <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
        <transparent>false</transparent>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <resizable>true</resizable>
        <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
        <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
        <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
        <width>1024</width>
        <height>768</height>
    </initialWindow>
    <icon>
        <image16x16>icons/pe-16x16.png</image16x16>
        <image32x32>icons/pe-32x32.png</image32x32>
        <image48x48>icons/pe-48x48.png</image48x48>
        <image128x128>icons/pe-48x48.png</image128x128>
    </icon>
</application>
```

All redirect.html does is redirect the user to a section of our website with Javascript.  After redirection, the page comes up and it is missing all of its images.  I also get this error in Terminal, over and over.

> 2015-11-02 09:30:34.375 adl[90787:4976353]
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>
> (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824) 2015-11-02 09:30:34.414
>   adl[90787:4976353] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)

I am running SSL in my local host environment and the redirect is to https.  I've found the exact same error in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9) on this site, but I am not sure how to apply their solution in Adobe Air, as their solution is for iOS.  Does anyone know any Air-specific solutions for this problem?

By the way, there are also several other errors at the top of the error list:

```
Nov  2 09:30:16  adl[90787] <Error>: The function ‘CGFontSetShouldUseMulticache’ is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance.
2015-11-02 09:30:31.181 adl[90787:4976353] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2015-11-02 09:30:31.222 adl[90787:4976353] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9802)
2015-11-02 09:30:31.262 adl[90787:4976353] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9802)
2015-11-02 09:30:31.262 adl[90787:4976353] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
TypeError: Result of expression 'document.getElementById('nav-close-btn')' [null] is not an object.
 at https://spear.dev/javascript/global.js?t=20150924 : 1380
```

I'm not sure what those errors mean.  I can't find these error numbers listed in Adobe's docs.  If someone could point me toward those, that would be great.  Remember this is NOT a Flash application.

I feel like this has to do with either the loading of the images on the page, which don't display.

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone else later.  The issue was that there was a different domain in the app than the SSL domain.  Even though it was an HTTPS call, Adobe was still complaining.  When I removed those calls, the app worked as expected, without errors.