# How to solve "CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cfnetwork

I am trying to fix CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) warning.
My app working well but when I run app through Xcode in device, app crashing.
I've added NSAppTransportSecurity in .plist,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Also Tested with different 3g/wifi's.

Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the crash related to ATS ? Please add the exception message.

Comment: I am using AFNetworking . I think crash is due to Network issue and not related to ATS , but due to some suggestion in stack overflow i am using ATS to prevent crash in real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9)

Also try with different versions of TLS like below.

```
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key> <string>TLSv1.1</string>
```

Also check with this by adding to your app's Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>YOUR_HOST.COM</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>1.0</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem. After reading this post [CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9), I put this on Info.plist and now works:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```