# Firebase in iOS: CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed despite configuration seem correct.

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, cfnetwork

**EDIT:**

I tested authentication from iOS on a demo project and it worked. So it is more likely to be some error on my side rather than a problem with Google's Firebase servers.

---

I am getting this error when trying to create a new Firebase user:

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806
```

When asking this question on Stackoverflow I get [this as suggested question with already an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9). It has currently 166 upvotes. However I don't think the answer applies to my firebase project as all the configuration necessary is already automatically generated by Google and included in the plist file I downloaded at the moment of setting up the project.

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

The firebase console says that there are issues with the Android version in terms of authentication. Are these the same?

Answer (score 0):

The Google generated plist file does not contain any ATS settings so if Firebase does not fulfil the ATS requirements, you will still have to add the exceptions described in your linked answer.

Did you try adding them?

Comment: No, it used to work fine until last week. Hence why I am asking.