# I have iOS 10 TSL issue ("Security Error: -9801"). How to fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, configuration

I have App which connects to SSL SOAP service. For iOS 9.3.5 the App works fine. From iOS 10 I have error with code `-9801`. I suppose this is connected to Apple ATS. The site certificate is configured for `TLS 1.0` (but I can not manage certificate configuration).

How can I fix this? I suppose I have to add it as an exception in `.plist` file.

I also made check with [www.ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com) and for section `Apple ATS 9 / iOS 9  R` it gives error:

> Protocol or cipher suite mismatch

but on iOS 9 it works.

*EDIT:*

I add the domain to ATS exceptions (in `info.plist`) but the error persists

Comment: There is no such thing as "certificate is configured for TLS 1.0" . The certificate is independent from the TLS version.  More help might maybe done if you don't just link to ssllabs in general but to the actual analysis for the server in question, because then one would say how it is configured and what might be the problem.

Comment: 10x for remark @SteffenUllrich. May be I have to say that the certificate minimum version is TSL 1.0, I am not expert. For the configuration you are right - I will add analysis.

Answer (score 1):

NSAppTransportSecurity

  NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

add this key - values in your `info.plist`, this means it will allow all kind of load. If you have specific domain then you should add that specific domain in `info.plist`.

**Update :**

If you need secure connection then you should manage your `info.plist` like,

```
     <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>yourdomain.com</key>
    <dict>
        <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

or you should use webservice which have `ssl` integrated!

Comment: I think I already described that :), @Lion. I will not allow `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, because I need secure connection.

Answer (score 1):

Use  ATS diagnostics mode in **nscurl** to get suggested content of ATS dictionary:

`nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://yourdomain.com --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

I found temporary workaround, but I will continue the investigation of TSL certificate configuration.

I added the `URL` for our service to ATS exceptions (more info [here](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)). Then I have to find out that ATS configuration is changed in iOS 10 and exception must be written as TSLv1.0 instead of 1.0 (I used exception example for other site and inside it was 1.0) - 10x to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30882037/3871718).