# iOS10 NSURLSession HTTP/2 Invalid

Tags: ios10, http2, charles-proxy

NSURLSession Request HTTP/2.0

working in iOS9.

[image]

but invalid in iOS10

[image]

my code :

```
 

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ga.seeyouyima.com/page"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (completedBlock) {
            completedBlock(data, response, error);
        }
    }] resume];
```

Comment: Your code is required.

Comment: May be there is a problem with certificate configuration. I have similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39544547/3871718).

Comment: server certificate use TLSv1.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like Charles Proxy 4 will cause iOS 10 to not use HTTP/2.  It seems to work fine with iOS 9.

You can demonstrate this by loading the Akamai HTTP/2 demo in Mobile Safari in iOS 10:

https://http2.akamai.com/demo

If you enable Charles Proxy while visiting the site it will report to you that your browser does not support HTTP/2.

Comment: This is right answer. Charles Proxy 4 makes iOS 10 not to use HTTP/2. Use iOS 9 if you need to sniff HTTP/2 request using Charles Proxy 4.

Comment: Also, for those that are wondering, the iOS 9 simulators do work for this.

Comment: I have the same behaviour with Charles and NSURLSession using HTTP 2 but this is kind if strange. Why would Charles make the HTTP 2 fail while it succeeds at proxying other HTTP 2 requests (e.g. curl)