# TIC TCP Conn Failed

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, urlsessiontask

Something have changes in the server I was using to fetch an .mjpeg video feed.

Now I'm getting this error:

> TIC TCP Conn Failed [5:0x1d4361380]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802)
>
> TIC TCP Conn Failed [6:0x1c0177a00]: 3:-9800 Err(-9800)
>
> TIC TCP Conn Failed [7:0x1d4361440]: 3:-9800 Err(-9800)
>
> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9800)
>
> Task <2B8346B5-6BB2-4B92-B311-554410CBF92F>.<1> HTTP load failed
>   (error code: -1200 [3:-9800])
>
> Task <2B8346B5-6BB2-4B92-B311-554410CBF92F>.<1> finished with error -
>   code: -1200

This is the code where I'm getting the error:

```
open func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

    var credential: URLCredential?
    var disposition: Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = .useCredential
    // Getting the authentication if stream asks it
    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
        if let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
            credential = URLCredential(trust: trust)
            disposition = .useCredential
        }
    } else if let onAuthentication = authenticationHandler {
        (disposition, credential) = onAuthentication(challenge)
    }

    completionHandler(disposition, credential)
}
```

I have already set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

To get the .mjpeg I'm using the code of MjpegStreamLib.

What can be wrong?

Comment: This link may be useful - see the comment by *Womble*
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9)

Comment: **I'm facing the same issue. In my case api server is blocked my ip address. When i have tried calling the api after connecting my phone's network to some other wifi or internet, its working fine.**

Comment: No I was not able to make it work, they change something again (I don't know what) and started to work again