# Upload an image from Android photo to Amazon S3 cloud

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I am creating an Android app that suppose to upload an image into the server. I am using Eclipse(HTML5 and Phonegap) and for the upload I use WCF service in visual studio. It works fine, now I need to use same process to upload a photo to Amazon S3. when I add 2 lines of credential to the Web.config of my wcf project I get an error and photos not uploaded. 
I add these 2 lines:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value=""/>
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value=""/>
</appSettings>
```

and I get this error in my android emulator:

Upload failed: code = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the answers of similar questions:

1) [Phonegap's FileTransfer.upload() throwing error code 3 on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783985/phonegaps-filetransfer-upload-throwing-error-code-3-on-android)

2) [Phonegap : FileTransfer.upload() fails on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522729/phonegap-filetransfer-upload-fails-on-android)

Hope that helps.