# filetransfer.download() fails with slow internet

Tags: javascript, cordova

I developed an App for iOS that downloads about 50 - 200 images with different sizes (max. 10mb). The app is working perfect when I test it in my WLAN (about 50mbit/s) but when my client starts the downloading process then the the error-code 3 from filetransfer.download() appears.

Does someone has issues lieke me?
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Setting chunkedmode false should be the key. Check out this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522729/phonegap-filetransfer-upload-fails-on-android

Comment: but i just download files i do not upload any files.. ??

Comment: Its more of a file transfer issue rather than upload or download i believe. Check this out - http://jcroucher.com/2013/08/29/phonegapcordova-filetransfer-error-3-android/ Let me know if it was useful

Answer (score 0):

Error code meanings:

```
1 = FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR 
2 = FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR 
3 = FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR 
4 = FileTransferError.ABORT_ERR 
5 = FileTransferError.NOT_MODIFIED_ERR
```

Try this:

```
fileTransfer.download(source, target, successCallback, errorCallback, trustAllHosts, {
    headers: {
        Connection: "close"
    }
})
```

It should solve your problem.

More info: http://grandiz.com/phonegap-development/phonegap-file-transfer-error-code-3-solved/

Comment: but i just download files i do not upload any files.. ??

Comment: @MathisHüttl Updated answer. Test the fix, and if it works, please mark this as an accepted answer, else, I'll try to clone a cordova seed project and try this out.

Comment: no it doesen work on slow internet when my inet is fast then there is no problem..